# DataContext of UserControl doesn't inherit from its parent Grid?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm implementing a feature that loads some user control to window (it shows the history of records for the object related to the user control)and so I send a List to that History window (varies from UC to another):
for example when the user click on the Area button in the application, I do this:

```
var frmHistory = new FrmHistory();
frmHistory.HistoryData = historylist;
var frm = new FrmArea(historylist[0]);
frmHistory.grdHistoryForm.Children.Add(frm);
frmHistory.ShowDialog();
```

this is what  `FrmHistory` looks (simplified):

```
<Window x:Class="App.Forms.Generics.FrmHistory"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="FrmHistory" Height="520" Width="650">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="3" Name="grdHistoryForm">
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I want to inject the user control into the `grdHistoryForm`, and set the `DataContext` of the `grdHistoryForm` to the `HistoryData` property (it's a list that I iterate over through a navigation buttons),
but when I do that the `DataContext` of the inner child doesn't get the value of the parent Grid,
in the constructor of the `FrmArea`, I sent the object directly and set the `DataContext` of the inner grid of that UC to that object and it works.
but what I need is to be able to set the `DataContext` of the `FrmHistory` :

```
public object HistoryData { get; set; }
```

I update the context via this method in the `FrmHistory`

```
  private void UpdateDataContext()
        {
            grdHistoryForm.DataContext = (HistoryData as IEnumerable<object>).ElementAt(CurrentIndex);
        }
```

Comment: Why don't just frmHistory.grdHistoryForm.DataContext = frmHistory.HistoryData?

Comment: HistoryData is IEnumerable<object>

Comment: So? What difference does it make? You can set the DataContext to any object.